# How to Format a text file to desired output

Tags: text-processing, awk

**Text File:**

```
 ***** Connected to QBBSC01 *****  

MO  
RXOTG-0


DEV              DCP  APUSAGE  APSTATE           64K  TEI  
RBLT2-161        1    UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
RBLT2-162        2    UNDEF    IDLE              YES  
RBLT2-163        3    UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
RBLT2-164        4    UNDEF    IDLE              YES


***** Disconnected from QBBSC01 *****

***** Connected to QBBSC04 *****

MO  
RXOTG-23  

DEV            DCP  APUSAGE  APSTATE           64K  TEI  
RBLT2-161        1  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
RBLT2-162        2  UNDEF    IDLE              YES  
RBLT2-163        3  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
RBLT2-164        4  UNDEF    IDLE              YES  
RBLT2-165        5  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
RBLT2-166        6  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
RBLT2-167        7  UNDEF    IDLE              NO  
RBLT2-168        8  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       NO  


***** Disconnected from QBBSC04 *****  

***** Connected to QBBSC05 *****  

MO  
RXOTG-7  

DEV            DCP  APUSAGE  APSTATE           64K  TEI  
RBLT2-161        1  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
RBLT2-162        2  UNDEF    IDLE              YES  
RBLT2-163        3  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
RBLT2-164        4  UNDEF    IDLE              YES  
RBLT2-165        5  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
RBLT2-166        6  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  


***** Disconnected from QBBSC05 *****
```

**Desired Output:**

```
NE      MO      DEV            DCP  APUSAGE  APSTATE           64K TEI  
QBBSC01 RXOTG-0 RBLT2-161        1  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
QBBSC01 RXOTG-0 RBLT2-162        2  UNDEF    IDLE              YES  
QBBSC01 RXOTG-0 RBLT2-163        3  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
QBBSC01 RXOTG-0 RBLT2-164        4  UNDEF    IDLE              YES  


NE      MO       DEV            DCP  APUSAGE  APSTATE           64K TEI  
QBBSC04 RXOTG-23 RBLT2-161        1  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
QBBSC04 RXOTG-23 RBLT2-162        2  UNDEF    IDLE              YES    
QBBSC04 RXOTG-23 RBLT2-163        3  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES    
QBBSC04 RXOTG-23 RBLT2-164        4  UNDEF    IDLE              YES  
QBBSC04 RXOTG-23 RBLT2-165        5  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
QBBSC04 RXOTG-23 RBLT2-166        6  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
QBBSC04 RXOTG-23 RBLT2-167        7  UNDEF    IDLE              NO  
QBBSC04 RXOTG-23 RBLT2-168        8  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       NO  


NE      MO      DEV            DCP  APUSAGE  APSTATE           64K  TEI  
QBBSCO5 RXOTG-7 RBLT2-161        1  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
QBBSCO5 RXOTG-7 RBLT2-162        2  UNDEF    IDLE              YES  
QBBSCO5 RXOTG-7 RBLT2-163        3  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
QBBSCO5 RXOTG-7 RBLT2-164        4  UNDEF    IDLE              YES  
QBBSCO5 RXOTG-7 RBLT2-165        5  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES  
QBBSCO5 RXOTG-7 RBLT2-166        6  UNCONC   SPEECH/DATA       YES
```

**Please do not put line numbers into consideration.**

Comment: It's customary (or good manners) to add some wording concerning how you want to achieve this and what you've tried so far.

Comment: That right roaima, but I'm beginner with this codes what i have tried so far is somewhat embarrassing believe me, you don't want to see that. Please help.

Comment: Please review the formatting of your question - it seems inconsistent. Are some lines - but not all - really prefixed by a `>` or is that a remnant of earlier formatting attempts? Do the delimiter strings really vary e.g. `***** *Connected` versus `***** Connected`?

Comment: Updated...@steeldriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear from the questions how the various fields may vary.  But for your example a simple `awk` program could look like this:

```
/Connected/ { NE=$4 }
/RXOTG/     { MO=$1 }
/DEV/       { printf "\n\nNE      %*s %s\n", -length(MO), "MO", $0 }
/RBLT2/     { print NE, MO, $0 }
```

Comment: It does get a bit less straightforward if the `RXOTG`s and `RBLT`s don't always have such a distinct format. I might suggest using `/^DEV/` etc. though. Extra cookie points for `%*s` :)

Comment: Yes, the code wasn't meant as the final solution, more of a draft.  I imagine one might have t tweak the patterns, but that requires a more detailed knowledge about the variation of the input.  Thanks for the extra cookie points! :)